# response-content-disposition query parameter filename encoding

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, non-ascii-characters

I need to change the download or open filename of an object on S3. Naturally I use the response-content-disposition query parameter and use the filename field. However I have been able to only use ASCII encoding and this becomes a problem when I need my filenames to be in alphabets with non ASCII characters like Japanese, Korean, Russian, Greek etc. I could not get the filename* field to work with S3. Is there a workaround here to get filenames with non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use double encoding. Your content-disposition header looks like below:
Open:
'inline; filename=' +  EncodingUtil.urlEncode(filename, 'ASCII') + ';
 filename*=UTF-8\'\'%85%A3%E3%A2%8F'

Download:
'attachment; filename=' +  EncodingUtil.urlEncode(filename, 'ASCII') + ';
 filename*=UTF-8\'\'%85%A3%E3%A2%8F'

Please mark this as Best Answer if this works for you

Comment: wow, what a coincidence mr asci. answer to my problem related to non-ascii chars arrived from a guy who's surname is asci. thank you so much :)